# How to compute the quantity of energy consumed by Contiki program?

Tags: contiki, energy

I would like to know if there is a way to compute the energy that would be consumed by a contiki program in a mote.

I have to programs, and I want to know which one of them is more efficient in terms of energy consumption.

I know there is a such for TinyOs: [Avrora](http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/Avrora), but I wonder if there is a simulator equivalent to it for Contiki-OS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PowerTrace](http://soda.swedish-ict.se/4112/1/T2011_05.pdf) is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the energest model for calculating the energy consumption for different activities. (cpu_ON, LPM, TX, RX)

Comment: But how to do that? can you share a link that explain in details how to do it?

Comment: It says it has some bugs but hope it helps